# Powershell Runspace error when executing for the first time for the day

Tags: powershell, runspace

```
"Exception getting "BaseName": "There is no Runspace available to run scripts in this thread. 
You can provide one in the DefaultRunspace property of the System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Runspace type. 
The script block you attempted to invoke was: $this.Name""
```

Now, the c# code to create the runspace are as below

### without credentials (Localhost)

```
return RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
```

### with credentials

```
                var secureString = new SecureString();
                PowerShell instance = PowerShell.Create();
                instance.AddScript(string.Format("ConvertTo-SecureString {0} -AsPlainText -Force", _strapppwd));
                foreach (PSObject psOutput in instance.Invoke())
                {
                    secureString = psOutput.BaseObject as SecureString;
                }
                var remoteCredential = new PSCredential(_strappuname, secureString);
                var connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo();
                connectionInfo.ComputerName =_strappip; ;
                connectionInfo.Credential = remoteCredential;
                var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);
                return runspace
```

Anyone else face the same issue? Need to fix this as soon as possible

If I ran the application class which throws the error, second time it works fine without any changes in code. No error is thrown. This is strange.

We do have a flush and close method for stoping the runspace.

Waiting for the proper solution for it.

Comment: `BaseName` is an ETS property of type `ScriptProperty`, which means that it runs _PowerShell code_ when you access it. If that access happens in C#, outside of PowerShell, you'll get the error message you see.

Comment: ahhh, Good to know. But how we can resolve that. I mean any fix for that?

Comment: Please update your question with the code that triggers the symptom.